# Obtain a one hot encoded representation of an image and computing loss

Tags: tensorflow

Currently I am trying to obtain a one-hot-encoded representation of an 84x84 grayscale image in TensorFlow. The result should be a 84x84x64 where 64 indicates the amount of bins for the pixel intensities (0-3, 4-7, ..., 252-255).

So far I tried the following:

```
one_hot_image = tf.div(self.frame, 4)
one_hot_image = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(tf.round(tf.reshape(one_hot_image, [-1, 84, 84])), tf.int32), 64, on_value=1.0, off_value=0.0, axis=-1)
```

However due to the cast I end up with the following error when computing the sigmoid cross entropy and performing an Adam optimisation step on the loss.

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph
>   for ops that do not support gradients, between variables.

The loss is computed on images of 84x84x64 to determine how related the original image and the reconstructed image is (implementing an auto-encoder). Any ideas or help is appreciated!

Comment: One hot encoding is usually used to encode labels, not images. What is your actual goal in applying one-hot encoding to images?

Comment: I am following the auto-encoder as described in:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.04717

Comment: You need to provide full code or at least a full traceback. From these two lines it is impossible to understand what is wrong.